# How do you switch between multiple JPanles in an application window?

Tags: java, swing

I have tried to `setVisible(null);` but it produces an `java.lang.NullPointerException`. the JPanel `setLayout(null);` which I think is the issue, I don't know how to resolve it. I,m using a card layout to reduce windows in the application. Any help would be appreciated.

```
final JPanel Signin = new JPanel();
contentPane.add(Signin, "name_12988058891368");
Signin.setLayout(null);

JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Signin.setVisible(false);
        Home.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: [So many similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+swap+jpanels). In the future, please search first.

Comment: And no, setting the layout to null isn't the issue. To debug a NPE, see the [canonical question on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Question closed as a duplicate. If you feel it was closed incorrectly, then please create and post your valid [mcve] and we'll see.